# error using perl - Proc::ProcessTable. works in cmd line, not in .pl file

Tags: perl, process, runtime-error

strangeness: via cmd line i am able to search for a process; yet via .pl file i get an error,

```
"Can't call method "table" on an undefined value".
```

CODE:

```
perl -e '
    use Proc::ProcessTable; 
    my $t = new Proc::ProcessTable;
    foreach $p (@{$t->table}) {
        foreach $f ($t->fields) { 
            my $result = $p->{fname} cmp "top"; 
            if($result == 0) { print $p->{pid}; }
        }
    }'
```

can someone help shed some light on what i may be missing?

UPDATED[added strict, and warnings/thx!] - now causes this error:

```
Global symbol "$p" requires explicit package name at x.services.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$t" requires explicit package name at x.services.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$t" requires explicit package name at x.services.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$p" requires explicit package name at x.services.pl line 9.
Global symbol "$t" requires explicit package name at x.services.pl line 9.
```

CODE:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/perl
2 use Net::SSH::Perl;
3 use Net::SSH::Expect;
4
5 use strict;
6 use warnings;
7
8 my $remote_host = "severid.company.com";
9 my $serviceInfo = `ssh $remote_host -l myuid -i /home/myuid/.ssh/authorized_keys perl -e 'use Proc::ProcessTable; my $p; my $t; $t = new Proc::ProcessTable; foreach $p (@{$t->table}){print "!"}'`;
10 exit(0);
```

SO, i am trying to get a pid# back using the Proc::ProcessTable, into a variable. if using these multiple cmds is not correct, what's the a proper way to do this?

Comment: Showing the code that works is good, but it's no replacement for showing the code that's giving you the problem!

Comment: One thing this question is missing is the code that produces the error.

Comment: dang/oops - here u go/thx:

use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Net::SSH::Expect;

$remote_host = "serverid.company.com";
my $serviceInfo = `ssh $remote_host -l myuid -i /home/myuid/.ssh/authorized_keys perl -e 'use Proc::ProcessTable; my $p; my $t = new Proc::ProcessTable; foreach $p (@{$t->table}){print "!"}'`;
exit(0);

Comment: @dcparham Add that to the question using the `edit` button, not the comments. We can hardly read it here

Comment: Oh I see. You copied and pasted this one-liner into a backtick command inside another Perl program and thought that would work? The variables get interpolated, and replaced with whatever their value is (or nothing). If you had used `use strict; use warnings;` you would never have had this problem.

Comment: btw - #!/usr/bin/perl - is in the file/missed copying it. it's all there, now.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that isn't working.

Comment: @dcparham Perhaps you missed when I said earlier that you should add the code to your question.

Comment: 1) If there's a problem with your question, fix the question rather than adding an (unreadable) comment. 2) It helps if you tag the people to whom you are replying when writing comments so they get notified. (e.g. "@ikegami, I updated my question with the information you requested") 3) Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! The error will become apparent.

Comment: @ikegami - understood. the strict, and warnings revealed the errors, "Global symbol "$p" requires explicit package name"; also for var $t. from my 4 months of using Perl that equates to me that i need "my" before a var. any other clues?

Comment: Why is your program trying to use a variable named `$p`? Keep in mind the error comes from the program on the local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first problem:

- You're using `Net::SSH` modules, but using 'system' commands to do the dirty work. One or other is redundant.
- Inlining perl into an ssh runs a risk of interpolation errors - how do you know where the `'` is getting handled? (e.g. your shell, ssh, remote shell, perl).
- What are you trying to do with your inlined perl? It looks like a very complicated way of doing `ps -ef | grep top`.

Would it not be more sensible to:

```
foreach  ( `/usr/bin/ssh $remote_host -l myuid -i /home/myuid/.ssh/authorized_keys ps -ef` ) {
    chomp;
    my ( $UID, $PID, $PPID, $C, $STIME, $TTY, $TIME, $CMD ) = split;
    if ( $cmd eq "top" ) { 
        print $PID; 
    }
}
```

(or something similar using Net::SSH);

Comment: thx! [i only had to chg $cmd to $CMD in the if] - which leads me to reveal the complexity of my goal: [1]pass in a pid name to remote server, look for its name + pid file#. if that combo exists then ignore; if not, then start the process [using the pid name].

have you brought me to where i need to pose a separate question? ultimately, is SSH the tool or is there another needed for passing parms?

Comment: Seriously? c'mon, guys - i will be more careful posting what info you need. but please do not put me in danger of not asking more questions here! i go to user groups in the area who respect this site and i'd like to tell them i can help provide answers, as i maintain good rep here. still learning Perl!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for helping; each of you contributed. Here is the final product that works. Fields are obfuscated, to cover proprietary info of a major corporation. I hope this complete solution will redeem me from some incomplete info posts resulting in getting nearly blacklisted here. Please consider undoing comments about me that may harm my reputation. Thanks again!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Net::SSH::Expect;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=dbname;host=serverid.company.com;port=3306",'myuid','password',{'RaiseError' => 1}) || return(0);
my $dbh_service_thresholds = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table"); #select all, then loop through the recordset.
$dbh_service_thresholds->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $thresholdResult;

while( my $thresholdResult = $dbh_service_thresholds->fetchrow_hashref() ) { 
    my %serviceInfo = ('service' , $thresholdResult->{'service_name'}, 'server', $thresholdResult->{'server'});
    #so now $serviceInfo has paired values of service_name and server - cycle through and check/stop/restart, etc them.
    $service_name= $serviceInfo{'service'}; #service is handle for field: service_name.
    $remote_host = $serviceInfo{'server'};  #server is handle for field: server.
    my $pidFile = "/home/myuid/" . $service_name . "_myuid.pid"; #pid file name.
    #my $pidNum = `ssh $remote_host -l myuid -i /home/myuid/.ssh/authorized_keys less /home/myuid/$pidFile`;
    my $pidNum = `ssh $remote_host -l myuid -i /home/myuid/.ssh/authorized_keys less $pidFile`; #read the pid #.
    my $pidMatchCounter = 0; #use to count if process is found running.

foreach ( `/usr/bin/ssh $remote_host -l myuid -i /home/myuid/.ssh/authorized_keys ps -ef` ) { #check all the processes for a particular service_name and server.
    chomp; #break up the data into chunks.
    my ( $UID, $PID, $PPID, $C, $STIME, $TTY, $TIME, $CMD ) = split; #into its field names.
if ( $CMD eq $service_name && $PID == $pidNum ) { #checking individual process for match of name and pid.

$pidMatchCounter++; 
#if match found, then this process exists, and ignore it.
        }
}#foreach

if( pidMatchCounter == 0 ) { #if this particular service_name is not found, then start the service.
my $remoteCmd = `ssh $remote_host -l myuid -i /home/myuid/.ssh/authorized_keys /sbin/service $service_name start`;
}

}#while

exit(0);
```